# Pair two sets such that the distance between elements is minimized

Tags: combinatorics, hungarian-algorithm

I have two sets `S_1` and `S_2`. Given these two sets, I need to pair each element from `S_1` with an element from `S_2`.

- The elements are not reusable, so if `S_1[A]` is paired with `S_2[D]`, then I cannot also pair `S_1[B]` with `S_2[D]`.
- The goal is to produce a pairing using all elements such that the distance of the pairing is minimized.
- The distance of the pairing is computed as the sum of the distance between each pair.
- Produce result with *lowest total* paired points value

**Are there any known algorithms for solving this type of problem efficiently?**

Part of the difficulty is that taking a greedy approach doesn't work. If `S_1 = [A, B, C]` and `S_2 = [D, E, F]`, and `distance(A, D) = 0.1`, `distance(A, E) = 0.3`, `distance(A, F) = 0.4`, you can't naively match `A` to `D` just because it has the lowest distance for this set. Suppose that `distance(B, D) = 0.1`, `distance(B, E) = 0.8`, and `distance(B, F) = 0.9`. If you naively choose to match `(A, D)` in the first iteration, then you actually make the overall distance higher because this forces you to match either `(B, E)` or `(B, D)`. It would be a better choice to match `(A, E)` and then allow `(B, D)` to match. This means you can't iterate over `S_1` and greedily assign matches based on the lowest distance between each element of `S_1` and the remaining elements of `S_2`.

This seems similar to the assignment problem, which I could solve using something like the Hungarian Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), but I believe that algorithm allows reusing elements, which won't work for my case.

Comment: You have put some background information in place and made observations. Now what code do you have that you can put in here and do you have a specific question regarding that we can assist with?

Comment: I added a little more information. The question is if there are known algorithms for this type of problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: This question might be what you would like.  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28141/find-the-smallest-summed-distances-by-uniquely-pairing-elements-of-one-set-to-el  That site is likely better suited for this type question :)

Comment: This sounds exactly like the Assignment Problem: "It is required to perform all tasks by assigning exactly one agent to each task and exactly one task to each agent in such a way that the total cost of the assignment is minimized." I don't know where you heard it allows elements to be reused.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken. Thanks for clarifying. Somehow I missed that...